# iOS – How to run OCUnit tests every time I run my application in simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ocunit

How do I configure so that OCUnit tests are running every time I choose to run my application on the simulator in Xcode? (Xcode 4.5.1)

My app runs the test fine if I go through <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>` but not when I choose to run my application. I then get this warning:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Tools/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests:81: warning: Skipping tests; the iPhoneSimulator platform does not currently support application-hosted tests (TEST_HOST set).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run OCUnit logic tests automatically before each build (run) of ios app in xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980025/how-to-run-ocunit-logic-tests-automatically-before-each-build-run-of-ios-app-i)

Comment: @bryanmac That unfortunately does not work for me. No tests are run.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7231882/563795); it describes how to configure Xcode to build you test target during every run of your app in the simulator.