# is there any way of forcing Xcode to compile my tests automatically

Tags: swift, xcode

so - I'm new to swift, but done lots of other languages - and I'm big into testing - I rely heavily on my tests to catch stuff - especially structurally.

I keep getting tripped up in Xcode - I hit "run" and it runs.. and I think I'm fine - then down the track I go to add another test, and find my test project doesn't even compile.

How do I make Xcode compile *all* the projects in the solution when I run any one of them, regardless of what I run.  I don't want to be able to run my app, if there's a compile error in my tests...  and I don't want to *ever* explicitly compile the test project.   In the perfect world, it would also *run* all the tests before running the app, so I can't even run the app if I have a test failure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980025/how-to-run-ocunit-logic-tests-automatically-before-each-build-run-of-ios-app-i

Comment: tried those suggestions - they seem to only be valid with older versions of Xcode - can't find any evidence of "test after build" existing anymore :(

Comment: Yes I was afraid of that. You might want to try AppCode instead... Also you will be a lot happier if you keep your testable code in a framework with its own unit tests, as this can be tested without leading the blasted Test Runner into the simulator.

Comment: Another suggestion is to use CI. It doesn't solve exactly the problem you're describing but it makes sure the tests are always passing.